# Dependencies from git aren't being installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, distutils

[p0](https://github.com/bettertutors/rest-api) depends on [p1](https://github.com/bettertutors/user-api), which in turn depends on [p2](https://github.com/bettertutors/sql-models). [p2](https://github.com/bettertutors/sql-models) isn't getting installed, everything else is.

I.e.: I get an `ImportError` in reference to [p2](https://github.com/bettertutors/sql-models) when I deploy [p0](https://github.com/bettertutors/rest-api) via Heroku.

Note that all have lines in their `requirements.txt` like so:

```
git+http://github.com/project/package
```

Additionally I have tried putting everything in `install_requires` and `dependency_links`, but that failed to find the pacakge on GitHub. Tried even to write [my own `deps_installer()`](https://gist.github.com/SamuelMarks/45a998a83dd60ddbadbc).

Comment: You can add bottle to bars requirements.txt by using the --editable flag, see [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#options)

Comment: Oh, so I need the `-e` flag? - Currently just have a `git+` line...

Comment: Using the -e flag will install the package in editable mode, in other words it'll create a symlink to the packacke instead of adding it to the pythons site-packages directory. Apologies for being an idiot, there might be more to this. How exactly do you import bottle within bar?

Comment: [`from bottle import Bottle, response, request`](https://github.com/bettertutors/user-api/blob/master/bettertutors_user_api.py#L1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with:

```
package_dir
```

In my `setuptool.setup` function call.

Removing that keyword argument completely resolved my issue.

Additionally I put all my requirements in `p0`'s "requirements.txt".

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems.

1. Declare dependencies using the `install_requires` argument to `setup()`, not with `requirements.txt`. pypa has [a description of the differences](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/requirements.html) and pip developer Donald Stufft has [some elaboration here](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/).
2. Your `__version__` handling doesn't work: your setup.py for bettertutors_rest_api contains `from bettertutors_rest_api import __version__`, which will import bettertutors_rest_api.py, but bettertutors_rest_api.py will try and create a `Bottle()` object when it's imported, which will fail if bottle hasn't already been installed, so setup.py will fail instead of getting a version. pypa has [advice on single-sourcing versions](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/single_source_version.html) (I use option 3).

Comment: Thanks, I've removed all use of `__version__`. Still can't resolve a git link (with `install_requires` and `dependency_links`). Any clue how?

Comment: Updated my repositories again, this time using `requirements.txt` for my github dependencies only. Now back to it not installing a package 3 levels down. I.e.: p0 deps on p1, p1 deps on p2. p2 isn't getting installed.

Comment: To be clear, "pip install foo" ignores any requirements.txt bundled with the foo distribution completely.

Comment: So what's the solution if I want to bring in dependencies from github across 3+ layers of packages?

Answer (score 1):

Pip will *only* look at a `requirements.txt` if you explicitly tell it to on the command line, with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Note that you can name that file anything you like, calling it requirements.txt is a convention, not a standard that is used anywhere in packaging.

Note that `user-api` has a dependency link to `sql-models` but doesn't actually have it listed in `install_requires`, so that will do nothing atm.

Comment: Thanks, however I've tried 12+ different combinations of those (see my commit history or [this comp.lang.python link](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.python/q5yrtlNnJBg)). None worked. I'm sure it's just a misconfiguration on my end, but unsure how to resolve.